# Bash - reverse an array

Tags: bash, shell-script, array, bash-array

Is there a simple way to reverse an array?

```
#!/bin/bash

array=(1 2 3 4 5 6 7)

echo "${array[@]}"
```

so I would get: `7 6 5 4 3 2 1`
instead of: `1 2 3 4 5 6 7`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I have answered the question as written, and this code reverses the array. (Printing the elements in reverse order without reversing the array is just a `for` loop counting down from the last element to zero.) This is a standard "swap first and last" algorithm.

```
array=(1 2 3 4 5 6 7)

min=0
max=$(( ${#array[@]} -1 ))

while [[ min -lt max ]]
do
    # Swap current first and last elements
    x="${array[$min]}"
    array[$min]="${array[$max]}"
    array[$max]="$x"
    
    # Move closer
    (( min++, max-- ))
done

echo "${array[@]}"
```

It works for arrays of odd and even length.

Comment: Please make a note that this doesn't work for sparse arrays.

Comment: @Isaac there's a solution on StackOverflow if you need to handle those.

Comment: Solved [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/412872/265604).

Answer (score 30):

Another unconventional approach:

```
#!/bin/bash

array=(1 2 3 4 5 6 7)

f() { array=("${BASH_ARGV[@]}"); }

shopt -s extdebug
f "${array[@]}"
shopt -u extdebug

echo "${array[@]}"
```

Output:

```
7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

If `extdebug` is enabled, array `BASH_ARGV` contains in a function all positional parameters in reverse order.

Comment: This is an awesome trick!

Comment: doesnt work if you use BASH_ARGV elsewhere in the script with values in it

Comment: Can be simplified to `f() ( shopt -s extdebug; echo "${BASH_ARGV[@]}" ); f {1..7}`

Comment: @ingydotnet This can be *confined* into **1** (recursive) function: [my two version of this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/739247/27653)

Answer (score 24):

Unconventional approach (all not pure `bash`):

- if all elements in an array are just one characters (like in the question) you can use `rev`:

  ```
   echo "${array[@]}" | rev
  ```
- otherwise if none of the array elements contain a new line:

  ```
   printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}" | tac | tr '\n' ' '; echo
  ```
- and if you can use `zsh`:

  ```
   echo ${(Oa)array}
  ```

Comment: just been looking up `tac`, as the opposite of `cat` quite good to remember, THANKS!

Comment: Though i like the idea of `rev`, i need to mention that `rev` will not work correctly for numbers with two digits. For example an array element of `12`  using rev will be printed as `21`. Give it a try ;-)

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou Yes, that will work only if all elements are one characters (numbers, letters, punctations, ...). That's why I gave also second, more general solution.

Comment: The zsh example works for me, but outputs as a string, not an array

Comment: the zsh example is great! the first time it did not work for me because I did not understand it was `(Oa)` and not a `0`.

Comment: This answer does not have a general bash solution. The first option cannot handle array elements with more than one character, the second option cannot handle array elements with new lines., and the third option is not a bash solution.

Answer (score 14):

If you actually want the reverse in another array:

```
reverse() {
    # first argument is the array to reverse
    # second is the output array
    declare -n arr="$1" rev="$2"
    for i in "${arr[@]}"
    do
        rev=("$i" "${rev[@]}")
    done
}
```

Then:

```
array=(1 2 3 4)
reverse array foo
echo "${foo[@]}"
```

Gives:

```
4 3 2 1
```

This should correctly handle cases where an array index is missing, say you had `array=([1]=1 [2]=2 [4]=4)`, in which case looping from 0 to the highest index may add additional, empty, elements.

Comment: Thanks for this one, it works pretty well, though for some reason `shellcheck` prints two warnings: `array=(1 2 3 4)` `<-- SC2034: array appears unused. Verify it or export it.` and for: `echo "${foo[@]}"` `<-- SC2154: foo is referenced but not assigned.`

Comment: @nath they're indirectly used, that's what the `declare` line is for.

Comment: Clever, but note that `declare -n` seems not to work in bash versions before 4.3.

Comment: For reference, it's called a "nameref".  "A variable can be assigned the _nameref_ attribute using the `-n` option to the `declare` or `local` builtin commands (see Bash Builtins) to create a _nameref_, or a reference to another variable." -- [GNU Bash Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameters.html)

Answer (score 12):

To swap the array positions in place (even with sparse arrays)(since bash 3.0):

```
#!/bin/bash
# Declare an sparse array to test:
array=([5]=101 [6]=202 [10]=303 [11]=404 [20]=505 [21]=606 [40]=707)
echo "Initial array values"
declare -p array

swaparray(){ local temp; temp="${array[$1]}"
             array[$1]="${array[$2]}"
             array[$2]="$temp"
           }

ind=("${!array[@]}")                         # non-sparse array of indexes.

min=-1; max="${#ind[@]}"                     # limits to one before real limits.
while [[ min++ -lt max-- ]]                  # move closer on each loop.
do
    swaparray "${ind[min]}" "${ind[max]}"    # Exchange first and last
done

echo "Final Array swapped in place"
declare -p array
echo "Final Array values"
echo "${array[@]}"
```

On execution:

```
./script
Initial array values
declare -a array=([5]="101" [6]="202" [10]="303" [11]="404" [20]="505" [21]="606" [40]="707")

Final Array swapped in place
declare -a array=([5]="707" [6]="606" [10]="505" [11]="404" [20]="303" [21]="202" [40]="101")

Final Array values
707 606 505 404 303 202 101
```

For older bash, you need to use a loop (in bash (since 2.04)) and using `$a` to avoid the trailing space:

```
#!/bin/bash

array=(101 202 303 404 505 606 707)
last=${#array[@]}

a=""
for (( i=last-1 ; i>=0 ; i-- ));do
    printf '%s%s' "$a" "${array[i]}"
    a=" "
done
echo
```

For bash since 2.03:

```
#!/bin/bash
array=(101 202 303 404 505 606 707)
last=${#array[@]}

a="";i=0
while [[ last -ge $((i+=1)) ]]; do 
    printf '%s%s' "$a" "${array[ last-i ]}"
    a=" "
done
echo
```

Also (using the bitwise negation operator) (since bash 4.2+):

```
#!/bin/bash
array=(101 202 303 404 505 606 707)
last=${#array[@]}

a=""
for (( i=0 ; i<last ; i++ )); do 
    printf '%s%s' "$a" "${array[~i]}"
    a=" "
done
echo
```

Comment: Addressing an array’s elements from the end backwards with negative subscripts  seems not to work in bash versions before 4.3.

Comment: Actually, addressing negative numbers was changed in 4.2-alpha. And the script with negated values works from that version. @G-Man [**p.**  Negative subscripts to indexed arrays, now treated as offsets from the maximum assigned index + 1.](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/CHANGES) but Bash-hackers reports incorrectly 4.1 [numerically indexed arrays can be accessed from the end using negative indexes](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/bashchanges)

Answer (score 6):

Ugly, unmaintainable, but one-liner:

```
eval eval echo "'\"\${array['{$((${#array[@]}-1))..0}']}\"'"
```

Comment: Not simpler, but shorter: `eval eval echo "'\"\${array[-'{1..${#array[@]}}']}\"'"`.

Comment: And even for sparse arrays: `ind=("${!array[@]}");eval eval echo "'\"\${array[ind[-'{1..${#array[@]}}']]}\"'"`

Comment: @Isaac But no longer one-liner and only ugly and unmaintainable for the sparse array version, unfortunately. (Should still be faster than pipes for small arrays, though.)

Comment: Well, technically, it is a "one-liner"; not a one command, yes, but a "one liner" it is. I agree, yes, very ugly and a maintenance problem, but fun to play with.

Comment: Nice hack. You can even make this work safely for creating a reversed array: `eval eval "'rev=(\$(printf \"%q \"' '\"\${array[-'{1..${#array[@]}}']}\"' '))'"`. This is for dense, non-empty arrays. Doing the same for sparse arrays should be possible too.

Answer (score 6):

To reverse an arbitrary array (which may contain any number of elements with any values):

With `zsh`:

```
array_reversed=("${(@Oa)array}")
```

With `bash` 4.4+, given that `bash` variables can't contain NUL bytes anyway, you can use GNU `tac -s ''` on the elements printed as NUL delimited records:

```
readarray -td '' array_reversed < <(
  ((${#array[@]})) && printf '%s\0' "${array[@]}" | tac -s '')
```

Note however that bash arrays were inspired from ksh arrays instead of csh/zsh arrays, and are more like associative arrays with keys limited to positive integers (so called *sparse arrays*), and that method doesn't preserve the keys of the arrays. For instance, for an array like:

```
array=( [3]=a [12]=b [42]=c )
```

You get

```
array_reversed=( [0]=c [1]=b [2]=a )
```

POSIXly, to reverse the one and only POSIX shell array (`$@`, made of `$1`, `$2`...) in place:

```
code='set --'
n=$#
while [ "$n" -gt 0 ]; do
  code="$code \"\${$n}\""
  n=$((n - 1))
done
eval "$code"
```

Answer (score 5):

Pure bash solution, would work as a one-liner.

```
$: for (( i=${#array[@]}-1; i>=0; i-- ))
>  do rev[${#rev[@]}]=${array[i]}
>  done
$: echo  "${rev[@]}"
7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

Comment: nice one!!! THX; here the one liner to copy :-)  ` array=(1 2 3 4 5 6 7); for (( i=${#array[@]}-1; i>=0; i-- ));do rev[${#rev[@]}]=${array[i]}; done; echo "${rev[@]}"`

Comment: Doing `rev+=( "${array[i]}" )` seems simpler.

Comment: Six of one, half-dozen of the other. I'm not fornd of that syntax, but have no reason for it - just prejudice and preference. You do you.

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/bin/bash
(a=(1 2 3 4 5) r=(); for e in "${a[@]}"; do r=("$e" "${r[@]}"); done; declare -p a r)
```

prints

```
declare -a a=([0]="1" [1]="2" [2]="3" [3]="4" [4]="5")
declare -a r=([0]="5" [1]="4" [2]="3" [3]="2" [4]="1")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

array=(1 2 3 4 5 6)
index=$((${#array[@]}-1))

for e in "${array[@]}"; do
  result[$((index--))]="$e"
done

echo "${result[@]}"
```

Comment: Or `index=${#array[@]}` and `result[--index]=$e`

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note that this answer is almost the same as [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/528085/377345).

Answer (score 0):

According to TIMTOWDI (There Is More Than One Way To Do It), here is my solution, reversing array `a` into `r`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -u
a=(1 2 3)
t=("${a[@]}")
declare -p a t
r=()
while [ "${#t[@]}" -gt 0 ]
do
    r+=("${t[-1]}")
    unset 't[-1]'
done
echo "${r[@]}"
declare -p r
```

When executing with BASH "4.4.23(1)-release (x86_64-suse-linux-gnu)" I got:

```bash
+ set -u
+ a=(1 2 3)
+ t=("${a[@]}")
+ declare -p a t
declare -a a=([0]="1" [1]="2" [2]="3")
declare -a t=([0]="1" [1]="2" [2]="3")
+ r=()
+ '[' 3 -gt 0 ']'
+ r+=("${t[-1]}")
+ unset 't[-1]'
+ '[' 2 -gt 0 ']'
+ r+=("${t[-1]}")
+ unset 't[-1]'
+ '[' 1 -gt 0 ']'
+ r+=("${t[-1]}")
+ unset 't[-1]'
+ '[' 0 -gt 0 ']'
+ echo 3 2 1
3 2 1
+ declare -p r
declare -a r=([0]="3" [1]="2" [2]="1")
```

Comment: Wasn't aware of that; thanks!

Comment: Well, thinking about it, the extra level of indirection isn't really needed. Originally I had associative arrays in mind, but reversing the keys doesn't really make any sense, so I simplified the solution.

Comment: You're still missing some quotes. Try it with `a=('*' $'a\nb' 'foo bar')` for instance or after `IFS=0123456789`.

Comment: Agreed, but the original question does not use such complicated items ;-) Also it's *one* pair of double-quotes missing, right?

Comment: `${#t[@]}` still asks the shell to split+glob it. In bash, you need to quote expansions in list contexts (and here it's in arguments to the `[` command so is a list context) unless you want split+glob. See also [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346)

Comment: OK, maybe the BASH manual should actually warn about that; I had always thought that it simply returns a number, namely the number of items in the array. The manual says "*${#name[subscript]} expands to the length of ${name[subscript]}.  If subscript  is *  or @, the expansion is the number of elements in the array.*"

Comment: It does, but if you forget to quote it, like for *any* parameter expansion, it is subjected to split+glob which you don't want here. I agree the bash manual (and the POSIX specification which still has many examples with missing quotes) should be more explicit. shellcheck can also be used to spot some of those mistakes.

Comment: OK, I read a lot about it, but honestly: Isn't the assumption for most BASH questions and answers that "IFS is set to a half-way reasonable value" (i.e.: "default")? I'd say 99.5% of all shell scripts will break if IFS is set in some bad way, and IMHO the solution is not to add quotes like mad everywhere, but to use a different language then. Also: If IFS contains `0`, would I have to quote `0`, too?

Comment: No, `$IFS` is only involved in `read` and unquoted parameter expansions, command substitutions and arithmetic expansions. Leaving those unquoted is invoking that feature. It's a bad design but that's how it is. If you don't intend to do `glob(split(var-contents))` you should use the quotes or switch to a shell with a saner design like rc, es or fish (or zsh though zsh still does empty removal upon unquoted expansions).

Answer (score 0):

## Two different versions

Inspired from [Cyrus's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/412894/27653) and [wiki.wooledge.org](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/118?highlight=%28BASH_ARGV%29).
Very quick as there are no loop and no forks!
... **On not too large bunch of data!!**, regarding [Stéphane Chazelas's comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/412868/bash-reverse-an-array/739247?noredirect=1#comment1418843_739247), if you plan to manipulate big bunch of datas,
you'd better mandate specialised tools!

And here, confined into one single function.

### Print submited array in reversed order:

```
printReverseArray () {
    if shopt -q extdebug; then
        printf "%s " "${BASH_ARGV[@]}"
    else
        shopt -s extdebug
        "${FUNCNAME}" "$@"
        shopt -u extdebug
    fi
}
```

Sample run:

```
printReverseArray world! good Hello
Hello good world!

printReverseArray baz "Foo bar"
Foo bar baz
```

### Reverse array variable:

```
reverseArray() { 
    if shopt -q extdebug; then
        _ArrayToReverse=("${BASH_ARGV[@]}")
    else
        local -n _ArrayToReverse=$1
        shopt -s extdebug
        "${FUNCNAME}" "${_ArrayToReverse[@]}"
        shopt -u extdebug
    fi
}
```

Then

```
myArray=({a..d}{1,2})
echo ${myArray[@]}
a1 a2 b1 b2 c1 c2 d1 d2

reverseArray myArray
echo ${myArray[@]}
d2 d1 c2 c1 b2 b1 a2 a1
```

Comment: Note that despite the fork and exec of `tac`, I find [my approach](/a/467924) is more than 10 times as fast as your *very quick* one on `array=( {1..10000} )` on my system for instance (0.07 vs 0.8 second). Remember bash is one of the slowest shells around, and doing things builtin is not always a guarantee that it will be faster, especially for large datasets (where efficiency matters most).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Correct! Answer edited! Anyway, if you plan to reverse repeatedly a small array, your solution will quickly become very slow.

Comment: Actually, I find that my approach is still faster even on an empty array. Not sure how bash can be so slow on yours that it would be slower than forking + executing + shoving data through pipes. Maybe the option processing is very slow in bash.

Comment: Just tested with `array=([0]="c" [1]="b" [2]="a")`: 1000x `reverseArray`  => 0.034s, while your approach: 1000x `readarray...tac)` => 4.882 seconds!!!

Comment: I don't know why I get so bad perf with your approach, I'll investigate a bit more when I have some time. That's with bash 5.1 on a 13 year old i5-based PC running Ubuntu 22.04. I get 2.6 vs 0.7 seconds for 1000x on `a=()` (where `tac` is not run) and 2.6 vs 2.3 for 1000x on `a=(x)`.

Comment: On another machine running Ubuntu 20.04 (bash 5.0), mine is only faster for empty arrays or for arrays of size > 150 items or about.

Comment: [Please continue in chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146033/from-bash-reverse-an-array)

Answer (score -1):

#### Bash

```
array=(1 2 3 4 5 6 7)
echo "${array[@]} " | tac -s ' '
```

Or

```
array=(1 2 3 4 5 6 7)
reverse=$(echo "${array[@]} " | tac -s ' ')
echo ${reverse[@]}
```

#### Result

7 6 5 4 3 2 1

#### Version

```
$ tac --version
tac (GNU coreutils) 8.28
```

Comment: `tac` was already mentioned: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/412874/260978, https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/467924/260978, https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/413176/260978

Comment: I appreciate this answer because it uses `tac -s ' '` to separate the input according to spaces. This makes the implementation short and easy to understand.

Comment: That being said, this answer has the drawback that the output  `reverse` is not an array.

Comment: In my environment the result seems to behave like an array if I iterate over it. Also, maybe it could become a proper array by modifying the line to surround the expression (before assignment) with parenthesis, like: `reverse=($(echo "${array[@]} " | tac -s ' '))`

Comment: `tac` won't work robustly unless you print with null byte as separator and use `-s ''` as shown in [Stéphane's answer](/a/467924/112566).

Answer (score -1):

You can also consider using `seq`:

```
array=(1 2 3 4 5 6 7)

for i in $(seq $((${#array[@]} - 1)) -1 0); do
    echo "${array[$i]}"
done
```

In FreeBSD you can omit the `-1` increment parameter:

```
for i in $(seq $((${#array[@]} - 1)) 0); do
    echo "${array[$i]}"
done
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't reverse the array, it merely prints it out in reverse order.

Comment: Agree, my point was also to consider indices access as an alternative..