# How to reverse shell arguments?

Tags: shell-script, posix

I know that it is possible to reverse `"$@"` using an array:

```
arr=( "$@" )
```

And [using this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/412870/265604), reverse the array.

But that requires a shell that has arrays.

It is also possible using `tac`:

```
set -- $( printf '%s\n' "$@" | tac )
```

But that breaks if the parameters have spaces, tabs or newlines (assuming the default value of `$IFS`) or contain wildcard characters (unless globbing is disabled beforehand) and removes empty elements, and requires the GNU `tac` command (using `tail -r` is slightly more portable outside of GNU systems but with some implementations fails on large input).

Is there a way to reverse shell positional arguments portably, without using an array, and that works even if arguments contain whitespaces or newlines or wildcards or are possibly empty?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Portably, no arrays required (only positional parameters) and works with spaces and newlines:

```
flag=''; for a in "$@"; do set -- "$a" ${flag-"$@"}; unset flag; done
```

Example:

```
$ set -- one "two 22" "three
> 333" four

$ printf '<%s>' "$@"; echo
<one><two 22><three
333><four>

$ flag=''; for a in "$@"; do set -- "$a" ${flag-"$@"}; unset flag; done

$ printf '<%s>' "$@"; echo
<four><three
333><two 22><one>
```

The value of `flag` controls the expansion of `${flag-"$@"}`. When `flag` is set, it expands to the value of `flag` (even if it is empty). So, when `flag` is `flag=''`, `${flag....}` expands to an empty value and it gets removed by the shell as it is unquoted. When the `flag` gets unset, the value of `${flag-"$@"}` gets expanded to the value at the right side of the `-`, that's the expansion of `"$@"`, so it becomes all the positional arguments (quoted, no empty value will get erased). Additionally, the variable `flag` ends up erased (unset) not affecting following code.

Answer (score 10):

When wanting to use no array for temporary storage, we can use the fact that a `for` loop *always* iterates over an unchanging static set of elements.  In a sense, we can use the loop *itself* as a temporary storage of the positional parameters while rebuilding the list in reverse order.

To be able to do this, we also need to empty the list on the first iteration.  The code below uses a simple flag to detect whether this has to be done or not.  When the list is emptied, the flag is toggled.

```
flag=true
for value do
    if "$flag"; then
        set --
        flag=false
    fi

    set -- "$value" "$@"
done
```

This is unfortunately quite slow, as the list of positional parameters is effectively *rebuilt in each iteration* (`set -- some-list` sets all positional parameters).  The `bash` shell takes about 50 seconds to reverse the integers between 1 and 10000, while `zsh` takes just over 15 seconds.

Using [Isaac's trick](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/560698/116858) with `${flag-"$@"}` (which expands to `"$@"` only if `flag` is unset) actually makes the whole thing run slower; 1 minute 50 seconds (!) in `bash` and 25 seconds in `zsh`.

I'm assuming this is due to some implementation particularities in how the shells perform the test on `$flag` and/or expand `"$@"` for the `${flag-"$@"}` expansion (the shell might possibly expand `"$@"` twice internally?).

---

If allowing ourselves to use an array as temporary storage (this would not be *standard*, but still fairly *portable* since we often know what shell we're writing our scripts for), we can use the value `$#` (the number of positional parameters) as an index into which to store the current value while looping over the positional parameters.  Decreasing this value using `shift` in each iteration gives the effect of inserting values from the end of the array towards the start.

In `bash`, arrays start at index 0, and since the `shift` comes after the assignment,  the last positional parameter will be stored at index 1 rather than 0. This has no consequence for how the code works in `bash`, it will still generate the correct result, but it makes it also work in `zsh` (which uses 1-based array indexes by default).

Code:

```
tmp=()
for value do
    tmp[$#]=$value
    shift
done

set -- "${tmp[@]}"
```

With `bash` or `zsh`, this uses about 0.6 seconds to reverse the integers between 1 and 10000.

Comment: A guess about Isaac's way being slower: checking if the variable is set is naively slower than expanding an always-set-in-the-shell variable, because the latter finishes after just consulting the shell's variables, while the former has to then also check environment variables after the shell variable lookup fails. (Checking for not-set environment variables is probably O(n) where n is the number of set environment variables due to how environment variables are typically implemented, while in-shell variables can be implemented as a hash map or something else with faster lookups.)

Answer (score 10):

Copied from [this answer of mine](/a/560420) to [Bash - print reversed file list using glob](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/560400), to reverse the list of positional parameters POSIXly:

```
eval "set -- $(awk 'BEGIN {for (i = ARGV[1]; i; i--) printf " \"${"i"}\""}' "$#")"
```

Or slightly more legible on several lines:

```
eval "set -- $(
  awk '
    BEGIN {
      for (i = ARGV[1]; i; i--)
        printf " \"${" i "}\""
    }' "$#"
)"
```

The idea being to use `awk` to help generate the `set -- "${3}" "${2}" "${1}"` shell code for `eval` to interpret when `"$@"` has 3 elements for instance.

For large  lists, it is likely to be significantly faster than using a shell loop especially one that rebuilds a list at each iteration. The `awk` code could be replaced by a shell loop that gives the same output (as @mosvy has shown in comments), but in my tests with bash5+gawk4.1, it's still twice as slow except for very short lists.

In `zsh`, you'd use the `Oa` parameter flag which is explicitly designed to reverse an array:

```
set -- "${(Oa)@}"
```

On my system (slightly slower than @Kusalananda's), and on a list of positional parameters obtained with `set $(seq 10000)`, with bash5 + gawk4.2.1, that `eval` approach takes 0.4s while [@Kusalananda's](/a/560707) takes 1 minute and [@Isaac's](/a/560698) takes 2 minutes (`zsh`'s `Oa` approach takes about 2 milliseconds).

With the `sh` and `awk` from busybox 1.30.1, those timings become: 0.06s, 11s, 11s respectively.

Comment: +1 I think this would be a better answer if you also showed an unrolled variant of that one-liner - currently it's a rather painful mental process to unwrap all the quotes and which strings become what at which level.

Comment: @mtraceur you can do the same trick in plain shell, and it won't be much slower: `eval "set -- $(i=$#; for a do printf ' "${%d}"' "$i"; i=$((i-1)); done)"`. I've used this trick a lot, especially when constructing `--foo arg1 --foo arg2 ...` cmd lists, but I didn't get much traction with it when when answering Qs here (maybe because the common cargo cult dogma is that eval = bad ;-))

Comment: @mosvy Nice! And yes, there is a dogma against `eval`. Which has very justified roots, but is somewhat misplaced to generalize so much for `sh`, because `sh` is so limited that some things just cannot be reasonably done without an `eval` - I even wrote a command-line tool and equivalent portable shell polyfill years ago called [`esceval`](https://github.com/mentalisttraceur/esceval) whose sole purpose is to portably quote strings so that any `sh` will `eval` them back to the same exact string, precisely because there's just some things you cannot do otherwise.

Comment: @mosvy There is a notable parallel where `eval` is genuinely not necessary in almost every language out there, and almost everything could be achieved otherwise, so the rare times when it is a good fit in `sh` gets caught in the cross-fire.  It's very similar to the dogma against `goto` and preprocessor macro "abuse" in C: in C++ and many other languages, you genuinely don't need those things, because there are better ways, so all occurrences of them are suspect - but C, like `sh`, is limited in a way that sometimes makes it the genuinely best solution available.

Comment: @mtraceur, I'm not sure how I can _unroll_ it more. `"\""` is how you specify a string containing a double quote in awk like in many other languages. That makes the code hard to read, but there's not much one can do about it. Adding a `-v double_quote='"'` seems a bit overkill here and I'm not sure it will help much wrt legibility.

Comment: @mosvy, yes, while `eval` is dangerous, at least we know it is. `eval` causes its arguments to be evaluated as shell code so it has to be used carefully, but so do `sh`, `awk`, `perl`, some `exit`, `printf`, `[`, `read`... if not used properly. I don't hear many people claiming they should not be used like for `eval`. Like for `eval`, they should be used properly. Avoiding a command injection vulnerability is often more difficult with those than with `eval` especially if you're not aware of the risk. See also [there](/q/172103)

Comment: @mtraceur I think Stéphane already did unroll it with his "to help generate" example.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Actually, it seems to me that, for example, an embedded `perl` command line is *much* easier to write safely than `eval`.  Once you've enclosed your `perl -e` command in single quotes and handled any interior single quotes (which are usually few or none), then it pretty much reads like a `#!/usr/bin/perl` script.  But somehow `eval` always ends up with a tangle of single quotes, double quotes and backslashes.  Backslashes in particular are *very* hard to read and comprehend (e.g. "leaning toothpick syndrome").

Comment: @jrw32982supportsMonica, my point is that we see people doing `perl -e "s/RE/$unsanitized_value/g"` or `printf '%08d\n' "$unsanitized_variable"` and it's often not immediately obvious to people that it's an ACE, and not that easy to fix. It's more obvious that `eval var$i=$unsanitized` is bad. That one is easily fixable: `eval "var$i=\$unsanitized"` (though of course, not all of them are as easily fixable or as obvious)

Comment: I agree for those examples, but of course they're on different levels of complication.  What's the ACE for your `printf` example?

Comment: @jrw32982supportsMonica, see [the link I gave above](/q/172103), try for instance after `unsanitized_variable='psvar[$(uname>&2)0]'` in ksh or zsh for instance.

Comment: I see. I've used that awful hacky misfeature to get a dynamically calculated `ksh88` prompt. I didn't know it applied in the various numeric contexts like `printf %d`.