# Reversing order of pdf files to be processed

Tags: xargs

Context: Catalina = zsh (preferred) or 16.04 Ubuntu = bash

A `qpdf` example indicates:

```
# To merge (concatenate) all the pages of a list of PDF files and save the result as a new PDF:
qpdf --empty --pages <file1.pdf> <file2.pdf> <file3.pdf> -- <output.pdf>
```

A set of .pdf files (with spaces in filenames), in a particular directory, are to be concatenated:

```
# Concatenate Drafts file to ../concatDrafts.pdf   (76 pdf files)
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/53754681/4953146
qpdf --empty --pages *.pdf -- out.pdf
```

Although [`qpdf` command](http://qpdf.sourceforge.net/files/qpdf-manual.html) is concatenates .pdf files, the reverse order of the .pdf files is to be concatenated.  The order of the files to be processed is returned by:

```
ls -r.pdf
```

To handle spaces in the .pdf file names:  [xargs research](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32589977/4953146) indicates the need for:

```
ls -r *.pdf | xargs -E '\n'
```

What is the the thought process to arrive at a command the pipes the output of ls into the `qpdf` command?

Comment: Mandatory ["do not parse `ls`" link](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). :)

Comment: Is another shell an option (zsh?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `zsh`, it would just be:

```
qpdf --empty --pages ./*.pdf(On) -- output.pdf
```

Where `On` is a [glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) to `o`rder the glob expansion in reverse (capital `O`, lower case would be for straight) order by `n`ame.

You could also add the `n` glob qualifier for that by-name ordering to be numerical:

```
qpdf --empty --pages ./*.pdf(nOn) -- output.pdf
```

Compare:

```
$ print -r ./*.pdf(On)
./file3.pdf ./file2.pdf ./file1.pdf ./file11.pdf ./file10.pdf
$ (LC_ALL=C; print -r ./*.pdf(On))
./file3.pdf ./file2.pdf ./file11.pdf ./file10.pdf ./file1.pdf
```

(in lexical order, `file10.pdf` comes before `file2.pdf`, and even before `file1.pdf` in locales where punctuation (here `.`) is ignored in first approximation when comparing strings).

With:

```
$ print -r ./*.pdf(nOn)
./file11.pdf ./file10.pdf ./file3.pdf ./file2.pdf ./file1.pdf
```

The `file10.pdf` comes after `file3.pdf` because with `n`, sequences of decimal digits are compared numerically (that's similar to what is done by GNU `ls -v` or GNU `sort -V`).

Comment: Thank you for the elegant solution & concise response.  I believe that the `(On)` glob qualifier reverses the order & solves the problem.  I do not understand the `(nOn)` glob qualifier numerical ordering: please consider posting a link to a simple concrete example.

Comment: @gatorback, see edit.

Comment: The Chazelas solution is elegant (minimalism) and the example is very helpful to those learning the craft.

Comment: Follow-on question regarding `./` posted: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/617789/what-purpose-does-dot-slash-serve

Answer (score 1):

(For a GNU bash shell)

You can use `tac` to reverse the list of the arguments going to `xargs`. For the `qpdf` command you run, we have to combine two more arguments: `--` and `out.pdf` at the end.

Here using the newline as the arguments separator, that means filenames
with newlines are not handled:

```bsh
printf "%s\n" "out.pdf" "--" *.pdf | tac | xargs -d'\n' qpdf --empty --pages
```

And here for any filenames, using the null separator:

```bsh
printf "%s\0" "out.pdf" "--" *.pdf | tac -s $'\0' | xargs -0 qpdf --empty --pages
```

I tested (GNU Bash shell on Linux), it concatenated the files in the expected reversed order.

Comment: Please see my test results https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VsAE.png

Comment: I see `command not found: tac` ! BTW for zsh, (I think) there could be a direct glob syntax.

Comment: `brew install coreutils` installed to provide `tac`

Comment: same errors returned after installing `tac`   Filenames has spaces which may not play nicely with tac

Comment: Filenames with spaces are handled. Please see edited answer for **where** this answer works. You need GNU utilities, xargs and tac, to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use answers to [*How to reverse shell arguments?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/560697/108618) to reverse what `*.pdf` expands to. First store this as positional parameters of the shell:

```
set -- *.pdf
```

Then use any good answer to the linked question. I choose [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/560698/108618):

```
flag=''; for a in "$@"; do set -- "$a" ${flag-"$@"}; unset flag; done
```

Now `"$@"` expands to what you want. Use it with your desired command:

```
qpdf --empty --pages "$@" -- out.pdf
```

If you don't want to lose old positional parameters then run the three commands in a subshell.